# AWS EC2 LAMP Vhosts all point to same folder

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, lamp, vhosts

I would like to have multiple domains going to the same EC2 instance. All will have same IP. I have setup multiple vhost files as domain1.com and domain2.com. I do not have anything special in any htaccess files or in the vhost files. I have the domains through GoDaddy, they are pointed to the EC2 IP. The issue I have is that both domain 1 and 2 go to the same folder and show the same index.html in the browser.

As per https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html I see that httpd.conf does not exist anymore and I do not see anything in apache2.conf for ghosts.

(As you can see the commented out things I have tried)

*** NOT using rout 53, I do not want to use this, unless I have too***

vhost files:

(domain 1)

```
#SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/tmp/stapling_cache(128000)
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_stapling_cache(128000)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLUseStapling on
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule domain1.com\/$ http://domain1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain1.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

(domain 2)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com
#    ServerPath "/domain2.com/"
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteRule "^(/domain2.com/.*)" "/html/domain2.com$1"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html/domain2.com>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule domain2.com\/$ http://domain2.com/index.php [NC]
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin me8@gmail.com
            ServerName domain1.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com
```

*********** EDIT ****************

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
sudo apachectl configtest 
Syntax OK
```

I have completed "sudo a2ensite" command on vhost files and restarted apache after them

******* EDIT ****************

in hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 domain1.com
127.0.1.2 domain2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details:
What Instance/LAMP are you using?
Are you configuring vhost correctly?

For Bitnami stacks, for example, you should add the correct add the following line to the end of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf:
Include "/path to your configuration file.conf”

restart apache:
$sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

---

For plain Ubuntu,(after having apache installed) you should include your configuration file as below:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

ensure to enable your virtual host file:
$sudo a2ensite example.com.conf

restart apache:
$sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: I have made edits to the question. Please let me know if you need any more info. I have completed the commands when I setup the host files. But The domains still pointed to the same folder.

Comment: Do you have two separate config files? one for each vhost?
each file should be inside the "/etc/apache2/sites-available/" folder.

Comment: yes I have 2 files. One for each domain. domain1.conf and domain2.conf in sites-available

Comment: You should put quotes in your directory:
  <Directory "path">

Take a look at the following sample config file as a guide:
https://gist.github.com/jnuc093/6507a95d1580eb992d8f

Hope that helps,

Comment: Tried the quotes and still all points to the same folder. It looks like this may be a lets encrypt issue. https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3103 I will create a new was instance and try without the SSL encryption

Answer (score 0):

So, after making a new instance I was able to set up multiple vhosts.They are all working. The issue must have been the let's encrypt cert. I will backup my configuration and try let's encrypt on this the instance. I will report my findings to this posting. Thank you all for your help on this.